# scrollWidth returns clientWidth instead of the actual content width when used with flex row-reverse

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

Please take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OXm4T2i0tw6UOEwaDSkx?p=preview

In Chrome, container `scrollWidth` value is `1616px` (correct). In Firefox and IE11 it is `940px` (the width of the container itselft, not the width of the contents).

If I set container's flex-direction to `row` instead of `row-reverse`, everything works fine.

Is this a bug in Firefox and IE? How do I fix this, or work this around?

Thanks.

Comment: I've also opened a bug at Firefox bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1322236

Comment: I changed to `row` and it still returns 940 in Edge/Firefox ....

Comment: Weird. For me, if I change to `row` instead of `row-reverse` on line 15 of the app.css file, Firefox alerts 1617px. I'm using Firefox 50.0.2 on Windows 8.1 x64. @LGSon, which Firefox version are you on?

Comment: It seems to be a plunker bug related to caching. If I run the plunker in a separate window by clicking 'Launch the preview in a separate window', everything works the way I have described in the original question post: for both Firefox and IE11 `row` returns ~1616px wherease `row-reverse` returns 940px.

Comment: Here's a plunker bug for this: https://github.com/filearts/plunker/issues/98

Comment: FF 50.0.2 ... and bug explains it

Comment: Could you please cancel the downvote then if it was yours?

Comment: I didn't down vote

Comment: ... but I did upvoted it now along with posting an answer

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work-around, I tested this with success in FF and Edge, where I first change the `flex-direction` property, read the value and then reset the property.

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TPG1YtJHZRzLDLF8E8zW?p=preview)

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.style.flexDirection = "row";
var temp = container.scrollWidth;
container.style.flexDirection = "row-reverse";
alert (temp + ' ' + container.scrollWidth);
```

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted, because it is the only one suggested, and anyway it proves to work and now I'm using this in my production code.